# Executing stored procedures in Parallel

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have 35 stored procedures that I need to run in parallel so as to reduce the execution time.

I came across concept of Agent jobs [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/541834/How-to-execute-multiple-long-running-SQL-Statement).

The link suggests using this piece of code to achieve this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ExecuteSQL_ByAgentJob_usp(
    @SqlStatemet            VARCHAR(4000),
    @SPNameOrStmntTitle     VARCHAR(100),
    @JobRunningUser         VARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @JobIdOut               UNIQUEIDENTIFIER OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;  

    DECLARE @JobId          UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
            @JobName        VARCHAR(250) = NULL,
            @DBName         VARCHAR(100) = DB_NAME(),
            @ServerName     VARCHAR(100) = @@SERVERNAME


    --Creating Unique Job Name by combining @SPNameOrStmntTitle and a GUID.     
    SET @JobName = @SPNameOrStmntTitle + '_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(64), NEWID()) 

    --Currently logged user name will be used to execute the job if not provided one.
    IF @JobRunningUser IS NULL
        SET @JobRunningUser = SUSER_NAME()

    --Adds a new job executed by the SQLServerAgent service
    EXECUTE msdb..sp_add_job @job_name = @JobName, @owner_login_name = @JobRunningUser, 
    @job_id = @JobId OUTPUT 

    --Targets the specified job at the specified server 
    EXECUTE msdb..sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @JobId, @server_name = @ServerName 

    --Tell job for its about its first step.
    EXECUTE msdb..sp_add_jobstep @job_id = @JobId, @step_name = 'Step1', @command 
    = @SqlStatemet,@database_name = @DBName, @on_success_action = 3 

    --Preparing the command to delete the job immediately after executing the statements 
    DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(250) = 'execute msdb..sp_delete_job @job_name=''' + @JobName + ''''

    EXECUTE msdb..sp_add_jobstep @job_id = @JobId, @step_name = 'Step2', @command = @sql 

    --Run the job
    EXECUTE msdb..sp_start_job @job_id = @JobId

    --Return the Job via output param.
    SET @JobIdOut = @JobId
END
```

Despite of having read this over and over, I still do not understand which part of it will help execute stored procedures in parallel? If possible, please shed some light on it. I am curious as hell to know which part of the script does this magic.

It is called like this :

```
SET @Itr = 1 --Seeting the initial value.
    SET @RecCount = (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM   @Scripts
        )

-----------------PART3------------------------------------
    WHILE (@Itr <= @RecCount)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @sql = t.Script
        FROM   @Scripts t
        WHERE  id = @Itr
        --Just o identify the script name getting first 10 char of the SP
        SET @ScriptTitle = LEFT(REPLACE(@sql, 'EXEC ', ''), 10) 

        EXEC ExecuteSQL_ByAgentJob_usp
             @SqlStatemet = @sql,
             @SPNameOrStmntTitle = @ScriptTitle,
             @JobRunningUser = 'sa',
             @JobIdOut = @JobId OUTPUT
```

Is it how it is called in a loop ? But I believe next iteration of loop will start only when last is done executing, so how come it runs in parallel ?

Comment: sp_start_job just starts the job, it does not wait until it finishes, and that's the idea behind that script

Comment: @Simran, You might consider using Service Broker for this task instead of SQL Server agent.  That will provide more control over the number of concurrent proc executions that might otherwise overwhelm the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. Next iteration will start when the last is done. But here, you are running jobs in those iterations not the actual statements. So imagine it like sp_start_job is called in async manner. It will just start the job and return immediately. The job itself may continue to do it's steps.

Answer (score 4):

On a side note why would you want 35 procedures to execute parallel ? to me this requirement sounds a bit unrealistic.

Even if you execute two stored procedures exactly at the same time, It is not guaranteed that they will go parallel.

Parallelism of executions is dependent on other factors like Query Cost, MXDOP(Maximum Degree of Parallelism), Threshold for Parallelism etc.

These properties are manipulated on the server level configuration (except the MAXDOP which can be specified on query.

I cannot go into too much details but my suggestion would, do not depend on Parallelism write your code in a way that it doesnt depend on queries being parallel, Also the somewhat simultaneous execution of queries is handled via Transactions.

Just as a hint to have 35 procedures being executed parallel you would need 35 cores on your Sql Server and MAXDOP Set to 1 and then have them 35 procs being executed at the exact time. Seems a lot of unrealistic requirements to me :)

Comment: All of them are not going to be executed in parallel. It's just that some of them in chunks will go on that way.

Comment: If you want to improve performance, running them in parallel is not necessarily going to help.If you have a resource bottleneck due to bad code this is definitely not going to help

Comment: any mircrosoft docs link regarding parallel sp execution

Answer (score 1):

The best, and easiest, way to do it is to create an SSIS project that has 35 Execute SQL tasks in parallel and then execute the job. The learning curve on using SSIS to do this is an hour or two and you can let SQL Server use as much resources as possible to execute the tasks as fast as possible. You don't have to mess around with maxops or anything else - SSIS will do it for you.

To see different ways to execute SSIS jobs try this link:
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1775/different-ways-to-execute-a-sql-server-ssis-package/

Comment: That sounds interesting. Could you please specify the download link to ssis ? I have been looking up for it but no luck.

Comment: Its a free tool (that comes with any paid edition of SQL Server) and its full name is SQL Server Integration Services. To create a package on SQL Server 2012 and above see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917.aspx

Comment: Oh, Mine is not a paid edition.I hope SQL server Agent services works without it ? I have been trying to use sql server agent but it is not starting either.

Comment: You need a paid edition of SQL Server to use the SQL Server Agent. EXPRESS doesn't let you